# Blur navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar, opacity, transparent

I want to have a page with navbar, background and also some form of foreground.
I want the foreground to be kind of transparent background above the original background but the problem is that my navigation bar go transparent also whenever I add opacity: .8 to my css code  and I can not click any of the options in the drop down menu

```css
body {
  background-image: url("bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #78706e;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: Times;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  ;
}

.ij {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #a5a5ad;
  padding: 30px;
  opacity: .8; //Here is the problem
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("m.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0a0d54;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Add this */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  right: 0;
  font-family: Times;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.png" alt="image" width="400" height="200">
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Academic</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Departments.html">Departments</a></li>
        <li><a href="Undergrad.html">Undergraduate Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="Grad.html">Graduate Programs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Admission</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="un.html">Undergraduate Admissions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Research</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="KeyResearch.html">Key Research Areas</a></li>
        <li><a href="Innovation.html">Innovation & Entrepreneurship</a></li>
        <li><a href="Highlight.html">Highlighted Units & Facilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="GradResearch.html">Graduate Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="UndergradResearch.html">Undergraduate Research</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Campus Life</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="StuLife.html">Student Life</a></li>
        <li><a href="Inclusion.html">Inclusion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="ij">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <h1> side </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-75">
        <h3>GLOBAL</h3>
        <h2>The Connected World </h2>
        <img src="img1.png" alt="img" hight="300" width="400">
        <p>Notre Dame seeks to be in the world, and to bring the world to Notre Dame, because inquiry and scholarly exchange are enriched by the pursuit of cultural fluency.</p>
        <h3>Faith & Service</h3>
        <h2>The Demands of Justice</h2>
        <img src="img2.png" alt="img" hight="300" width="400">
        <p>Notre Dame is animated by a faith that inspires us to seek knowledge because of the powerful tool it can be to improve humankind.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <video width="600" controls>
  <source src="University of Notre Dame du Lac.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>



  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/notredame/"> FACEBOOK</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/NotreDame/"> TWITTER </a> &copy 2019 University of Notre Dame Notre Dame, IN 46556 USA 41.703234 -86.238985 Phone: (574) 631-5000

</div>
```

Comment: Try adjusting the alpha value of rgba instead of your opacity, though this is based off of your css, without the HTML can't make accurate assumptions, please do provide the HTML too

Comment: I will try and I did add the html code

Answer (score 1):

Try this for blur transparent nav

```
nav ul li {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(44, 43, 43, 0.53);   /*   Add this rgba color  */
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```